# Creating a function that negates return value of another function

Tags: python, function

I am new to Python 3 and currently practicing with functions. I wanted to first write a function that returns `True` or `False` depending on whether its parameter (int) is even.

```
def isEven(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return True
    elif number % 2 != 0:
        return False
```

This worked as I could print the return value with the `print()` function.
However, I had problems when I wanted to write a second function, which is the `isOdd()` function. I wanted it to negate the whatever return value of `isEven()`. I tried:

```
def isOdd (number):
    return not isEven(number)
```

Is there a more efficient way, say, by creating a conditional statement in `isOdd()`?

Comment: Do you even need `isOdd`? Anything that is not even is odd, simply `def is_even(number): return number % 2 == 0`

Comment: What's the problem with your current approach? I don't see any major inefficiency in it.

Comment: In `isEven`, why `elif`?  A number is either divisible by 2 or it isn't, so `else` should suffice.

Comment: If you're after performance, it's better to create two functions - `isEven` and `isOdd` each handling a different case (i.e. `return number % 2 == 0` and `return number % 2 != 0` respectively), than negating the output of another function - code verbosity hurts performance far less than additional function calls. For simple tasks like this you should probably not use functions at all - I personally find it easier to write `not my_number % 2` than to add a function call like `isEven(my_number)`  to my code.

Comment: @zwer One case where an `isEven` function could be useful is when one is planning to do pass this function as parameter to other functions: looks nicer than using lambda expressions every time.

Comment: @chris_rands fair point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you might not need `isOdd()`, since `isEven()` will return false then.

You can also eliminate the if-elif statement:

```
def isEven(number):
    return number%2 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about only this example then you can use if. But if isEven is bigger in realtime world, you should call it in isOdd

I'd minimize isEven with like this

```
def isEven(number):
    return number % 2 == 0
```